# Can't find the error in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I cant find the error in this SQL.

```
INSERT INTO "mod_vehicles_models" (make, name, name_slug, fuel, mass, cylinder_capacity, cylinder_count, energy_label, emission, usage_avg, usage_city, usage_high, capacity_pull_weight, capacity_carry_weight) VALUES ("alfa romeo","alfa romeo 147","alfa-romeo/alfa-romeo-147","benzine","1165","1598","4","","192","8,1","11,1","6,3","1300","")
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Answer (score 1):

Write the table name without quotes :

```
INSERT INTO mod_vehicles_models(make, name, name_slug, fuel, mass,
     cylinder_capacity, cylinder_count, energy_label, emission, usage_avg,
     usage_city, usage_high, capacity_pull_weight, capacity_carry_weight)
     VALUES ("alfa romeo","alfa romeo
     147","alfa-romeo/alfa-romeo-147","benzine","1165","1598","4","","192","8,1","11,1","6,3","1300","")
```

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO "mod_vehicles_models" - remove quotes from table name